# Dagger 2 Unable to provide and inject Interface and its implementation in android

Tags: android

```
@Module
abstract class  PersonUsecaseModule{
    @Provides
    internal fun provideUseCase(useCase: GetPersonUseCaseImpl): PersonUseCase = useCase

    @Provides
    internal fun provideMutableLiveData() = MutableLiveData<PersonUseCase.Result>()

    @Provides
    internal fun providePersonWidgetImplScreen(widget: PersonWidgetImpl): PersonWidget = widget

}
```

this is my module class  and i am injecting it in MainActivity i am getting error

error: com.anil.gorestapp.person.injection.PersonUsecaseModule is abstract and has instance @Provides methods. Consider making the methods static or including a non-abstract subclass of the module instead.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {

I don't know why i am getting this Error Please help me what i am doing mistake

```
lateinit var personWidget: PersonWidget
```

AppLication component :

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [

            ApplicationModule::class,
            ActivityModule::class,
            NetworkModule::class
        ]
)
interface ApplicationComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: MainApplication)
}
```

ActivityModule

```
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindSharedPreferences(appPreferenceImpl: AppPreferenceImpl): AppPreference

}
```

person module

```
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindSharedPreferences(appPreferenceImpl: AppPreferenceImpl): AppPreference

}
```

Comment: Are you injecting constructor of PersonWidget?

Comment: yes i am injecting  like this class PersonWidgetImpl @Inject constructor() : PersonWidget{

Comment: Can you try providing some String from this module just for test purpose.

Comment: I tried like this  @Provides
    fun provideServerUrl(): String? {
        return "https://www.vogella.com/"
    } still same error

Comment: In that case give these answers, Are you Registering your module in Component? if Yes then Are you registering your component in your Activity?

Comment: Please check i have updated my code provide component and binding an all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is, You have declared your module as "abstract" and along with this, you are also using @Provides annotation on methods which are returning implementation of interface.

Dagger doesn't allow that. You can fix this issue in two way:

First Way: Remove abstract from your module like this:

```
@Module
class ActivityModule {
@Provides
fun providePersonWidget(personWidget: PersonWidgetImpl) : PersonWidget = personWidget
}
```

Second way: Use @Bind annotation on method instead of provide like this

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
@Binds
abstract fun providePersonWidget(personWidget: PersonWidgetImpl) : PersonWidget
}
```

Note: In second way you can declare your method and class as abstract but cannot return anything.

If you are still not very clear with my answer, you can refer this branch which I have created for you.

https://github.com/parmeshtoyou/StackOverflow/compare/sof_23_oct_21_dagger_issue?expand=1

Comment: but when i try to update dagger to 2.38.1 i am getting public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector(…, injectorFactoriesWithStringKeys)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.app.Activity> is injected at
          com.anil.gorestapp.MainApplication.activityInjector
      com.anil.gorestapp.MainApplication is injected at    ApplicationComponent.inject(com.anil.gorestapp.MainApplication)

Comment: have you made any other change as well apart from updating dagger version? I am also hoping that you are injecting your activity from AppComponent  like fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

Comment: No i have not changes anything  and i am injecting interface ApplicationComponent {
    Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: MainApplication)
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}

Comment: can you push your code on GitHub if possible, I will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me https://github.com/anilthakur/GoRestApp. actually i want design project so learning i am trying to per activity or fragment there should be one module that what we need to inject in fragment we can inject it and use it but some common module should like network ,database, sharedpreferces should be inject on application level but widget  should in activity level or fragment level

Comment: I have raised pull request here. please review these changes. https://github.com/anilthakur/GoRestApp/pull/1

Comment: i did some  small changes  but  at runtime i am getting      Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized  unable to run app i have pushed changes  after apply you changes then also its crash if could help i will thank full for you

Comment: have you checked my PR?

Comment: yes i  did but at runtime it show view mode not intilize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238474/discussion-between-marsh-and-parmesh).